# Return a query from inside a block

Tags: ios, parse-platform

i hope NSlog outside of block can have value.
i don't know how to fix it. i hope loadPuppiesFromJSON can working.
could somebody help me!?THX!!

```
- (id)init
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {

        allPuppies=[self loadPuppiesFromJSON];

    }
    return self;
}

 - (NSArray *)loadPuppiesFromJSON 
     {
     PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Information"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) { 
     if (!error) {           
          // The find succeeded.           
          // Do something with the found objects           
          for (PFObject *object in objects) {                
            Fish *fish = [[Fish alloc]init];                
            fish.price = object[@"price"];                
            fish.name = object[@"name"];                
            [object saveInBackground];               
            self.allFishes = objects;                          
            NSLog(@"%@",allFishes);<-----here have some value        
        } else {
           // Log details of the failure  
          NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]); 
       }
   }];
    NSLog(@"%@",allFishes);<----here doesn't have value
}
```

Comment: You are initializing an object that requires data to be pulled from Parse before the object is ready. This is a bad idea- it means that if you can't reach parse, your program will crash. You need to re-think how you are initializing the object and where you are using the data.

Comment: OK,i will think about again. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `NSLog(@"%@",allFishes);` doesn't have a value is that it is being called before your query is complete. It's a [Race Condition](http://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/race-condition), and at run-time here is what the program thinks you want:

1. Start query
2. Call NSLog outside the block - no data yet, so it's empty
3. Call completion block when it is ready - this is when the data is generated so you get a populated NSLog here

Since you also want to have the value return, try this instead - just remove your NSLost from outside the block and call a second function with the return value to continue your logic:

```
- (void)loadPuppiesFromJSON 
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Information"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) { 
    if (!error) {           
        // The find succeeded.           
        // Do something with the found objects           
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {                
          Fish *fish = [[Fish alloc]init];                
          fish.price = object[@"price"];                
          fish.name = object[@"name"];                
          [object saveInBackground];
          }               
        self.allFishes = objects;                          
        NSLog(@"%@",allFishes);<-----here have some value    
        [self processPuppiesArray:objects];
      } else {
          // Log details of the failure  
          NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]); 
      }
   }];
   //No NSLog out here - it won't do anything
}

- (void)processPuppiesArray:(NSArray *)puppiesArray 
{
    //Continue processing here...
}
```

Comment: THX! but Control reaches end of non-void function. i don't know why.

Comment: You had set up the function to process your results before they were ready - that's what the `(NSArray)` part of `- (NSArray *)loadPuppiesFromJSON` does. I edited my answer to reflect using a second function so you can process the array when it is ready.

Comment: well, i change my post. could u see it again?THX^^

Answer (score 0):

The NSLog where you are not getting any value is because block is called in background after it completes your function execution. Thats why before executing you block, it finishes your function execution and during that time allFishes variable is empty/nil. Once the block excution starts and assigns value to allFishes after that this variable gets the value.
If you need to execute some code after allFishes have value create a function and call it after blockexecution finishes like below:

```
- (NSArray *)loadPuppiesFromJSON 
{
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Information"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) { 
if (!error) {           
    // The find succeeded.           
    // Do something with the found objects           
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {                
        Fish *fish = [[Fish alloc]init];                
        fish.price = object[@"price"];                
        fish.name = object[@"name"];                
        [object saveInBackground];               
        self.allFishes = objects;                          
        NSLog(@"%@",allFishes);<-----here have some value
        [self dataLoadFinished];        
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure  
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]); 
    }
}];
NSLog(@"%@",allFishes);<----here doesn't have value
}


-(void) dataLoadFinished {
    NSLog(@"%@",self.allFishes);<----here you will have value 
}
```

Comment: THX! the function actually have value. but loadPuppiesFromJSON have a warn "Control reaches end of non-void function".

Comment: oh right... you need to return an NSArray from this function or set return type as void.

Comment: well, i change my post. could u see it again?THX^^

Comment: Well best way to do is using Delegation or NSNotification. Your approach will not work

Answer (score 0):

The reason you aren't retrieving any data is because you are trying to retrieve an Array from a function but never return anything.

When you use the -(NSArray *)loadPuppiesFromJSON you actually have to return an Array which you are not doing.

For example:

```
-(NSArray *)loadPuppiesFromJson {
NSArray *allFishes;
allFishes = @[@"someinfo1",@"someinfo2",@"someinfo3"];

return allFishes; // this is where your getting your error and need for it to return anything
}
```

I would suggest butting your code into a void function like so:

```
-(void)loadPuppiesFromJSON {
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Information"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) { 
 if (!error) {           
      self.allFishes = objects;                
      for (PFObject *object in objects) {                
        Fish *fish = [[Fish alloc]init];                
        fish.price = object[@"price"];                
        fish.name = object[@"name"];                
        [object saveInBackground];                        
    } else {
       // Log details of the failure  
      NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]); 
   }
 }];
 NSLog(@"%@",allFishes);<----here has value now
 }
```

And call it in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear or wherever you need it with:

```
[self loadPuppiesFromJSON]
```